# How can I load javascript file into the same directory of my html on Ruby On Rails 4 [Spree commerce]

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, render, spree, sprockets

I had problems to

`<%= render :partial... %>`

using Javascript **(js.erb)** in my **Frontend** of Spree. I've found sprockets has problems to render into

> /assets/

, the only way I think is locate the .js.erb into the same directory where my html.erb is located.

I'm using rails 4, spree 2.2-stable

How can I do that? thanks in advanced.